# How to make an if-else condition for WordPress multiple subdomains?

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

This code working fine on my wordpress site pages.

```
<?php 
if ( is_page('pt') ) {
  $language = 'pt';
} 
  else if( is_page('es') ) {
    $language = 'es';
  }
     else {
  $language = 'en';
     }

?>

<?php echo $language; ?>
```

I have 4 subdomains under main domain.

like:

1. example.domain.com
2. example1.domain.com
3. example2.domain.com

I want to apply the same coding method for subdomains.

For Example:

```
<?php 
if ( is subdomain example.domain.com ) {
  $language = 'pt';
} 
  else if( is subdomain example1.domain.com ) {
    $language = 'es';
  }

  else if( is subdomain example2.domain.com ) {
    $language = 'ar';
  }
    
     else {
  $language = 'en';
     }

?>
```

How can I do print variables for subdomain same as WordPress is_page condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST'];

switch($domain){

case 'example.domain.com': Your code...;

break;

case 'example1.domain.com': Your code...;

break;

case 'example2.domain.com': Your code...;

break;

default: Your code...;

}
}
```

Comment: I have never seen `$_SERVER['HTTPS_HOST']` anywhere. Might be some specific server setup that fills this entry(?), but usually you would just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, regardless of whether the request was made using HTTP or HTTPS.